# c++ synchronized_queue/threaded app crashing at startup without specific reason

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

i'm using a Producer/2 Consumers design pattern and im facing a strange issue of crashing at startup.
I tried with GDB but it is telling me about "Unknown source" / Cygwin.S missing.
In any case no matter where i put the breakpoints, if i "continue" on the code it inevitably crashes with SIGSEV on Thread 5 (no idea what Thread 5 is, probably the t_b below).

Here is the partial code of it

```
//similar for B
struct dataA {
    int a;
    float b;
    int c;
    //...
}

//similar for B
union typeA {
   char byte[SIZE_A];
   struct dataA d;
}

union typeA a;
union typeB b; //2megabyte of data

SynchronizedQueue<typeA> a_queue;
SynchronizedQueue<typeB> b_queue;

void a_Thread()
{
    for (;;){
        typeA a = a_queue.get();
        cout << "a: " << a.d.c << endl; //Pseudo code
    }

}

void b_Thread()
{
    for (;;){
        typeB b = b_queue.get();
        cout << "b: " << b.d.a << endl; //Pseudo code
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    thread t_a(a_Thread);
    thread t_b(b_Thread); 

    //open a file ecc

    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
        //logical code

        if (case_A){
            typeA data = xyz;
            //or int data = 7;
            a_queue.put(data);
        } else if (case_B){
            typeB data = qwe;
            //or int data = 7;
            b_queue.put(data);
        }
    }

    //close file
    return 0;
}
```

If i comment out

```
thread t_b(b_Thread);
```

everthing works as expected but if i do the same for t_a the problem still exist, hence i suspect it has something to do with t_b.
Keep in mind that the code crashes even before reaching the "put" statements.

While for t_a it works with the datatype i want (the end goal is to use a union/struct), for t_b it works when using e.g int but it doesnt when i use my own data (2MB of union/struct).
Moreover since the two unions/structs are global i'm not sure if i'm thread safe, my understanding is that i'm passing a pointer to the queue so potentially i might have race conditions if the consumer takes a lot of time. For this case i suspect the solution would be to make a memcpy of a local union/struct and consume it.

EDIT:
SynchronizedQueue implementation
https://home.deib.polimi.it/fornacia/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=teaching:aos:2017:aos_l4_multithreading_cpp.pdf p42

EDIT 2:
Here is the code snippet

main.cpp

```
#include "synchronized_queue.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

struct dataA {
    int a;
    float b;
    int c;
};

union typeA {
   char byte[2300000];
   struct dataA d;
};

struct dataB {
    uint8_t a;
    float b;
    double c;
};

union typeB {
   char byte[20500];
   struct dataB d;
};

union typeA a;
union typeB b; //2megabyte of data

SynchronizedQueue<typeA> a_queue;
SynchronizedQueue<typeB> b_queue;

void a_Thread()
{
    for(;;){
        typeA _a = a_queue.get();
        cout << "a: " << _a.d.c << endl;
    } 
}

void b_Thread()
{
    for(;;){
        typeB _b = b_queue.get();
        cout << "b: " << _b.d.c << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{  
    thread t_a(a_Thread);
    thread t_b(b_Thread);

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        if(rand() % 100 + 1 > 50){
            typeA a;
            a.d.a = 10;
            a.d.b = 10.2;
            a.d.c = 10;
            a_queue.put(a);
        } else {
            typeB b;
            b.d.a = 70;
            b.d.b = 70.5;
            b.d.c = 70.3658485226;
            b_queue.put(b);
        }
    }

    //a_queue.finish();
    //b_queue.finish();

    //t_a.join();
    //t_b.join();

    return 0;
}
```

synchronized_queue.h

```
#ifndef SYNC_QUEUE_H_
#define SYNC_QUEUE_H_
#include <list>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>

template <typename T>
class SynchronizedQueue
{
public:
    SynchronizedQueue(){};
    void put(const T &data);
    T get();
    size_t size();

private:
    SynchronizedQueue(const SynchronizedQueue &) = delete;
    SynchronizedQueue &operator=(const SynchronizedQueue &) = delete;
    std::list<T> queue;
    std::mutex myMutex;
    std::condition_variable myCv;
};

template <typename T>
void SynchronizedQueue<T>::put(const T &data)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(myMutex);
    queue.push_back(data);
    myCv.notify_one();
}

template <typename T>
T SynchronizedQueue<T>::get()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(myMutex);
    while (queue.empty())
        myCv.wait(lck);
    T result = queue.front();
    queue.pop_front();
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
size_t SynchronizedQueue<T>::size()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(myMutex);
    return queue.size();
}

#endif // SYNC_QUEUE_H_
```

if one changes 2300000 to 23000 the code works!

Comment: What is `SynchronizedQueue`?  Will it be happy with 2MB of data?

Comment: https://home.deib.polimi.it/fornacia/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=teaching:aos:2017:aos_l4_multithreading_cpp.pdf
page 43 on wards

Comment: What exactly is `typeB`?  Does it obey the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)?

Comment: You need to join your threads before they are destructed. If you don't, bad things will happen when your program terminates. Also `union` is *very* suspect. How can it possibly make sense to have a `union` as type in a container? Please provide a full [repro].

Comment: Hope this helps, regarding reproducible ill try to create a union of simply 2 chars array to see if it still happens

Comment: In this case how do i signal the end of the program? i mean when the while loop is over i should wait for them to end but how should i communicate it from the main function? using a variable? if so how?

Comment: Is future overkill? https://thispointer.com/c11-how-to-stop-or-terminate-a-thread/

Comment: maybe std::atomic<bool> m_exit{false}; might be enough

Comment: @Luigi You need to use the "@" comment syntax to notify others of your comments.

Comment: Your code will cause a stack overflow in the thread stacks if the union types are too large , because of `_a` and `_b`. Also note that it doesn't really make sense to use a union. You are not  allowed to inspect the non-active member anyway and so, because you cannot know which member is active when you call `get()`, you can never use the other member legally. For thread termination, the easiest way would be to reuse the queue and send a termination notice via the queue which will cause the threads to exit when `main` requests it. `main` then just needs to call `.join()`.

Comment: I dont get the reason why i get the overflow, how do i avoid that? I'm quite sure 2MB of data is not that huge. Since if i only let the non-threaded part everything works. Regarding the inspection i dont understand as well, the queue is a template of unions so when the thread consumes them it should be able to access the "char" part of it. Regarding thread termination can you provide a small example? Since it is waiting on a conditional variable i need to notify_all and somehow return a NULL union and then check on an atomic variable if it is time to exit from the for loop of the thread?

Comment: On unix the code works without any issue, i suspect it has something to do with the size. Do we have a way to use c++1 thread and change a stack size on windows/gcc? Also is there a non-invasive change/modification e.g. using boost threads (how?) to overcome this issue?

Comment: Further to the previous comments regarding unions, why not make use of [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)?  It's type-safe and the buffer member `byte` could, if still required, be of type `std::vector<char>` or similar.

Comment: Can you point me exactly to why there is an issu on using a union?